# Reactjs set state true or false

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, state

How can i set state for loaderSimpleStory() and FlightStatusStory  .

When loaderSimpleStory() is true FlightStatusStory will be false and vice versa.

```
const LoadingStory = () => {
  return (
    <div className="content-wrapper">
      {loaderSimpleStory()}
      <div className="container-subnav">
        <FlightStatusStory />
      </div>
      <div className="headline">{headlineSimpleStory()}</div>
      {linkSimpleStory()}
      {richTextSimpleStory()}
    </div>
  );
};
```

any help would be really helpful.

Comment: Does the value returend from loaderSimpleStory() ever change? If it doesnt then you might always be stuck with it unless you use some sort of state or props change.

Comment: @ChristopherNgo i need to make it in a such a way that loaderSimpleStory()will set state false when FlightStatusStory state is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const LoadingStory = () => {
    const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        setStatus(loaderSimpleStory()); 
    },[])

    return (
        <div className="content-wrapper">
            {status == null && loaderSimpleStory()}
            <div className="container-subnav">
                {status !== null && <FlightStatusStory status={!status} />}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: const FlightStatusStory = (props) => {
    const {status} = props; // false

    return ();
}

here return() for what ?

Comment: Write down the jsx you want to return from FlightStatusStory.

Comment: But loaderSimpleStory() is not loading before the FlightStatusStory .
It should be loaded before.

Comment: As in my original code i posted it is a loader which will show loader before rendering FlightStatusStory